# What the name of this plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]
The plants are located in Asia and I forgot the plants name

Comment: sorry, our policy is one plant, one question.  Please remove the second photo and ask as a new question

Comment: Looks like *Fluffy Ruffles* Fern. Most ferns have flatter fronds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The said plant is Boston fern. Probably they can be grown anywhere, they aren't native to Asia but to Central Americas. There are also, other fern varieties endemic to Asia.